# React-Native: Enable Performance Monitor in production build

Tags: react-native

I am working on react-native automated UI test for iOS and I want to get the UI and JS FPS from the performance monitor.

I can enable and get those value in debug mode, but in production mode I cannot enable the performance monitor even I update the settings to force enable in AppDelegate

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *settings = [defaults objectForKey:@"RCTDevMenu"];
NSMutableDictionary *newSettings = [NSMutableDictionary   dictionaryWithDictionary:settings];
newSettings[@"RCTPerfMonitorKey"] = @1;
newSettings[@"showFPS"] = @1;
[defaults setObject:newSettings forKey:@"RCTDevMenu"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Are there any ways to open the performance monitor in production build?

Answer (score 2):

Found out that we can create a new schema in React.xcodeproj and set the RCT_DEV=1 in Preprocessor Marcos to enable the development menu even in production build.