# How to delete "dropped s far" from my react native application?

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a react native application and I don't know why some statistics are shown in my app (top left of screenshot), is there any way to hide this overlay?

[image]

Comment: So that people can still benefit from this question after a while, please add the screenshot to the question, and explain that you're talking about the graphics statistics at the top right. As it's written, this relies on external data (the image link).

Comment: @tar I don't think he is allowed to insert images with reputation of 1

Comment: @SvenBardos Exactley I can't add a screenshot

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277990/react-native-enable-performance-monitor-in-production-build ? He's trying to activate them in production. Find the settings and disable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the React Native Perf Monitor.

You need to open the Developer Menu and click *Hide Perf Monitor*.

[Opening the Developer Menu](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging)